# Filepicker Implementation Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

I am currently trying to use filepicker on my Meteor project. I have been able to successfully show the pick a file button via front end, click, load the filepicker widget and upload a file. I am using the free storage with 5000 images. Filpicker confirms I have uploaded 30 files already. I am not sure how to get the URL and store it on my mongo DB. I am very new to development. I am using Coffee script. This is what I have:

Initializing:

```
Template.MyTemplate.rendered = () ->
    filepicker.setKey("AouIUs8H6RnuPwHB5gqOyz")
    filepicker.constructWidget(document.getElementById('attachment'))
```

Event Handler:

```
Template.MyTemplate.events
'change #attachment': () ->
console.log "attachment changed"
```

HTML

```
<div class="dataEntry">
    Your File  <input type="filepicker" id="attachment"/>
</div>
```

Not sure how to see the returned URL for the file and how to store it. I would much appreciate your support. As I mentioned I am new to this so if possible when in doubt don't assume I know. Thanks! - M

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [filepicker-plus](https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/filepicker-plus).

Comment: Thanks David, I will look into it. Appreciate the hint.